# How to determine if Aspose.Words bookmark contains nested bookmarks

Tags: c#, aspose, aspose.words

I'm using the following code to iterate through all of the bookmarks in a Microsoft Word document:

```
foreach (var bookmark in _document.Range.Bookmarks.Cast<Bookmark>())
{
    //code
}
```

How can I determine if `bookmark` contains nested bookmarks? I need to execute a separate set of logic based on whether or not a bookmark has other bookmarks within it.

Answer (score 0):

The above foreach loop will get all the instances of Bookmark. To get the nested bookmark is a bit tricky, as there is no direct API in Aspose.Words to do this.

I have written a program to do this, the source code is not tiny, so I am sharing the Visual Studio project on Google Drive [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6S7uu28AdY0ZURYTFR2UG91Tjg&authuser=1).

Below is the summary

```
foreach (var bookmark in wordDoc.Range.Bookmarks.Cast<Aspose.Words.Bookmark>())
{
    Console.WriteLine(bookmark.Name);
    // Get all the nodes between bookmark start and end
    ArrayList extractedNodes = ExtractContent(bookmark.BookmarkStart, bookmark.BookmarkEnd, true);
    for (int i = 0; i < extractedNodes.Count; i++)
    {
        // Skip first and last nodes
        if (i == 0 || i == extractedNodes.Count - 1)
            continue;

        // See if there is any bookmarks in this node
        Node node = (Node)extractedNodes[i];
        if (node.Range.Bookmarks.Count > 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Nested bookmark found");
    }
}
```

For details of ExtractContent() method, please visit http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/Extract+Content+Overview+and+Code